# Why the behaviour differs when fgets() is used instead gets()

Tags: c, fgets, gets

as per `gcc` warning:

> the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used

I try to use `fgets()` but it does not wok out in my code as you may see the outputs for both at the end of code below. May someone please tell me what mistake (if any) I am doing?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define size 128

int Table[size];

/****ShiftTable Function Declaration****/
void ShiftTable(char Pattern[]);

/****Horspool Function Declaration****/
int Horspool(char Pattern[],char Text[]);

/****Main Function****/
int main()
   {
    char Text[100],Pattern[100];
    int pos;

    printf("Enter the Text : ");
    gets(Text);                    //Works fine
    //fgets(Text,100,stdin);       //Does not work

    printf("\nEnter the Pattern: ");
    gets(Pattern);                 //Works fine
    //fgets(Pattern,100,stdin);    //Does not Work

    pos=Horspool(Pattern,Text);

    if(pos==-1)
            printf("\nPattern Not Found!\n\n");
    else
        printf("\nPattern Found at %d position.\n\n",pos+1);        

    return 0;
   }

/****Horspool Function Definition****/
int Horspool(char Pattern[],char Text[])
   {
    int m,n,i,k;

    n=strlen(Text);
    m=strlen(Pattern);

    ShiftTable(Pattern);

    i=m-1;

    while(i<n)
         {
        k=0;
        while(k<m && (Text[i-k]==Pattern[m-1-k]))  k++;

        if(k==m)   return i-m+1;

        i+=Table[Text[i]];
         }

    return -1;
    }

/****ShifTable Function Definition****/
void ShiftTable(char Pattern[])
    {
    int i,m;
    m=strlen(Pattern);

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        Table[i]=m;

    for(i=0;i<m-1;i++)
        Table[Pattern[i]]=m-1-i;
    }
```

***Output:***

When I use `gets()`

> majid@majid-K53SC:~ $ ./a.out
>
> Enter the Text : BANGALORE IS GARDEN CITY
>
> Enter the Pattern: GARDEN
>
> Pattern Found at 14 position.

When I use `fgets()`

> majid@majid-K53SC:~ $ ./a.out
>
> Enter the Text : BANGALORE IS GARDEN CITY
>
> Enter the Pattern: GARDEN
>
> Pattern Not Found!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fgets` consumes the newline character (you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering the string) and stores it in `Text` while `gets` does not. You'll need to [strip the newline character off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input) from `Text`.

So, after both the calls to `gets`,

```
Text = "BANGALORE IS GARDEN CITY"
Pattern = "GARDEN"
```

and in the case of `fgets`,

```
Text = "BANGALORE IS GARDEN CITY\n"
Pattern = "GARDEN\n"
```

Comment: I tried two method given in the link but they didn't work out, I don.t know what is the problem... I'm getting tired of fgets() ! please tell me what is wrong: 
either   strtok(Pattern,"\n"); 
or        ln = strlen(Pattern);
           Pattern[ln] = '\0';
makes it to go to infinite loop!

Comment: @MajidNK , Use `size_t ln = strlen(Pattern); if(ln != 0) Pattern[ln-1] = '\0';`. You can do the same for `Text` if you wish

Comment: Where are you using it? Use that just after the second `fgets`.

Comment: yes I'm using exactly after second fgets() and interestingly when pattern is something that matches  from 1st position of Text it works but any other thing it goes to infinite loop. It should be something with fgets as gets() works fine.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe something is wrong with your code. Could you post the updated code? You can also post a new question giving relevant details if you want.

Comment: I don't think code is wrong as it works with gets() but sure I try some more times with code and if no hope I ll ask new question. Thanks for your time

Comment: Got it :) It was problem of size //size must be atleast 128 to include asci codes of all keys in keyboard... it was 100 so for upper-case letter had no problem but when lower case was input it had gone to infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

First, thank you for paying heed to the warning. You're very right to switch to `fegts()`.

Now, to answer your question,

> *Why the behaviour differs when  fgets() is used instead gets()?*

That is not a weird behaviour. That is the expected behaviour of `fgets()`.

Unlike `gets()`, [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) **reads and stores** the trailing `newline` into the supplied input buffer. You need to strip off the newline before you go on for the comparison.

Without that, essentially, your inputs look like:

```
Text    --> "BANGALORE IS GARDEN CITY\n"
Pattern --> "GARDEN\n"
```

Now, as we know, a `"GARDEN "` and `"GARDEN\n"` are *not* same, so your comparison fails.

That said, just a suggestion, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.